# "draft saved" notification moves content in the preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, design

When editing a post, the notification "draft saved" appears in the preview pane.

When this notification appears, the first line of the preview content gets moved to the right.

[image: Preview pane without the notification]

[image: Preview pane showing the notification]

IIRC, this did not happen with the old design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will go live after our next production build.